# Combine cells that fall within one range

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation, textjoin

I have a set of data with numbers in Column A, then in column B and C there is data in multiple rows per number.  I would like to combine each column of data such that there is only one row per number.

For example, what I have is:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lorem | red |
|  | ipsum | orange |
|  | dolor | yellow |
|  | sit | green |
|  | amet | blue |
| 2 | Lorem | red |
|  | ipsum | orange |
|  | dolor | yellow |
| 3 | Lorem | red |
|  | ipsum | orange |
|  | dolor | yellow |
|  | sit | green |

And what I would like to get is:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet | red orange yellow green blue |
| 2 | Lorem ipsum dolor | red orange yellow |
| 3 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit | red orange yellow green |

Unfortunately the number of rows between each number in column A varies. Is there a way I can do this with VBA?

I've used textjoin to combine cells manually, but I can't figure out how to specify the ranges, and then continue for the entire document.

Comment: *Is there a way I can do this with VBA?* Yes, please post the code you've tried

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic spill formula for ***Microsoft-365*** user's.

```
=LET(i,SCAN(A2,A2:A13,LAMBDA(a,x,IF(x="",a,x))),
j,UNIQUE(i),
k,MAP(j,LAMBDA(t,TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,FILTER(B2:B13,i=t)))),
l,MAP(j,LAMBDA(m,TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,FILTER(C2:C13,i=m)))),
HSTACK(j,k,l))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Transform Data To Delimited

```
=LET(Data,A2:D21,Delimiter,", ",
    uData,TAKE(Data,,1),u,TOCOL(uData,3),urs,SEQUENCE(ROWS(uData)),
    vData,DROP(Data,,1),vcs,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(vData)),
    vss,FILTER(urs,(uData<>"")*urs),vrs,DROP(VSTACK(vss-1,ROWS(Data)),1)-vss+1,
    v,DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(u)),LAMBDA(rRes,rr,LET(
        vr,INDEX(vData,SEQUENCE(INDEX(vrs,rr,1),,INDEX(vss,rr,1)),vcs),
    VSTACK(rRes,BYCOL(vr,LAMBDA(br,TEXTJOIN(Delimiter,0,br))))))),1),
Result,HSTACK(u,v),Result)
```

- Replace the last occurrence of `Result` with any of the variables to better understand how it works. You can't see the results of the lambda variables though.

[image]